# Where is it possible to store additional file specific data in FILE_OBJECT

Tags: windows, filter-driver

I develop file system filter driver(or minifilter) for Windows XP and later. I need to store additional data specific for file. For example unique encryption key for file(every file is encrypted by unique key).
Where can filter driver store this data in FILE_OBJECT?
If data cannot be stored in FILE_OBJECT, where can it be stored else?

Thanks in advance